# rename file with progressive enumeration

Tags: dos, renaming

I have a file called mycat.avi inside a folder VIDEO
so that the path is c:\video\mycat.avi

now I would like rename it so that the new re-name become start from C0700.mxf

IF in folder c:\video is jet present another C0700.mxf -----> the file have to renamed C0701.mxf

if in folder c:\video is jet present another C0701.mxf -----> the file have to renamed C0702.mxf

if in folder c:\video is jet present another C0702.mxf -----> the file have to renamed C0703.mxf

... and so on

Supposing mycat.avi become renamed as C0716.mxf (so that now is present as c:\video\C0716.mxf)

--> after the renaming operation, tha batch have to create a .avs file (located alwais in the c:\video folder) that are called mycat_is_C0716.avs that contains:

FFVideoSource("c:\video\C0716.mxf")

So finally, in c:\video
are present only this files: C0716.mxf and mycat_is_C0716.avs

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to know ? how to build the batch ? rename ?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\video"
for /L %%a in (0700,1,9999) do (
   if exist "mycat.avi" if not exist "C%%a.mxf" (
      ren "mycat.avi" "C%%a.mxf"
      >"mycat_is_C%%a.avs" echo FFVideoSource^("c:\video\C%%a.mxf"^)
   )
)
pause
```