# batch that see files in ftp and choose a filename that are not in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

please I would like do a batch that do this:

it go on my local ftp site 192.168.0.18
admin is admin
password is pdw-f800

it go on folder called "clip"

In this "clip" folder there are many .mxf files recorder by a camera as:
C0001.mxf
C0002.mxf
C0003.mxf
C0004.mxf
... and so on

It have to put in a enviroment variable the name of .mxf file that are not the present in the folder and that start from C1700.mxf

For example: if in folder are present C0001.mxf C0002.mxf C0003.mxf C0004.mxf C0005.mxf ----> the batch have to put in the enviroment variable C1700.mxf.

But if there are already present C1700.mxf, the batch have to put C1701.mxf

If C1701.mxf is already present, the batch have to put C1702.mxf and so on

The batch have to suggest a filename that are not present in the folder, with starting from C1700.mxf

2 Days ago I have request a similar answer but now I have to do a similar operation on a ftp site and I'm not able to do this in a ftp folder.

How can I do? thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160804/rename-file-with-progressive-enumeration/26164149#26164149

Comment: so ... you tried something. What was the result? Please post your code along with a detailed description of your problem, and a precise question. We will be happy to help.

Comment: I cannot list files in a ftp site, I don't know how I have to do